# Turn off default sound when displaying MessageBox in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is there a way to turn off the sound that the Messagebox plays when it is displayed in WP7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to change this behaviour with the Silverlight MessageBox class. If, however, you use [Guide.BeginShowMessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940234.aspx) (from the XNA libraries) you can control whether sounds are played or not.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently there is no way you can disable the sound that is triggered by the `MessageBox` class. That is a feature tied to the system and unless the device is on mute, the sound will be played.

With XNA's async version you can do this, though (as mentioned by Matt):

```
Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Title", "Text", new List<string>() { "OK" }, 0, MessageBoxIcon.None, new AsyncCallback(YourCallback), null);
```

Here, `MessageBoxIcon` defines the sound and not the icon (which is nonexistent on Windows Phone for a `MessageBox`).

**Note:** you need yo add a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices`.